# Passing parameters in rails redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do we pass parameters in redirect_to in rails?
I know we can pass id using this:

```
redirect_to :action => action_name,:id => 3
```

If I want to pass additional parameters like some form data how to achieve it?

**EDIT:**

For Ruby 2 syntax you have to update the snippet above to:

```
redirect_to action: action_name, id: 3
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Have you considered saving the data in the session?

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible -- if you're doing a redirect, it must be a GET request that you're redirecting to, so the params will always be visible to your users. You should store stuff in the session instead.

Answer (score 187):

Just append them to the options:

```
redirect_to controller: 'thing', action: 'edit', id: 3, something: 'else'
```

Would yield `/thing/3/edit?something=else`

Comment: You can't redirect with a POST.  From the HTTP 1.1 docs under the 3xx definitions: "The action required MAY be carried out by the user agent without interaction with the user if and only if the method used in the second request is GET or HEAD."

Expand on what you're really trying to accomplish and we can probably push you in the correct direction.

Comment: Hi Thank a lot for your response.I am a newbie to web development.
I am trying to know different ways to invoke an action.Your response has clarified lots of my doubts.

Thanks again :))

Answer (score 92):

If you are using RESTful resources you can do the following:

```
redirect_to action_name_resource_path(resource_object, param_1: 'value_1', param_2: 'value_2')

or
#You can also use the object_id instead of the object
redirect_to action_name_resource_path(resource_object_id, param_1: 'value_1', param_2: 'value_2')

or
#if its a collection action like index, you can omit the id as follows
redirect_to action_name_resource_path(param_1: 'value_1', param_2: 'value_2')

#An example with nested resource is as follows:
redirect_to edit_user_project_path(@user, @project, param_1: 'value_1', param_2: 'value_2')
```

Answer (score 52):

If you have some form data for example sent to home#action, now you want to redirect them to house#act while keeping the parameters, you can do this

`redirect_to act_house_path(request.parameters)`

Comment: Do you know how you would combine this, plus new parameters? i.e. request.parameters, (or +) :this => :that

Comment: You could use the merge method. For example: `redirect_to act_house_path(request.parameters.merge(key: "value"))`

Comment: You could also use the except method to exclude unwanted params after merging: `redirect_to act_house_path(request.parameters.except(:authenticity_token, :controller, :action, :utf8, :commit)`

Answer (score 39):

You can pass arbitrary objects to the template with the flash parameter.

```
 redirect_to :back, flash: {new_solution_errors: solution.errors}
```

And then access them in the template via the hash.

```
<% flash[:new_solution_errors].each do |err| %>
```

Comment: This is poor practice. This method misuses the flash object, its intended for user messaging. Better would be to store arbitrary parameters in the session and then clear those parameters from the session when you're done.

Answer (score 33):

```
redirect_to new_user_path(:id => 1, :contact_id => 3, :name => 'suleman')
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are looking for a way to pass additional URL parameters (not controller, action, id, etc), here's a robust method for doing so:

```
object_path(@object, params: request.query_parameters)
```

That will pass along **utm parameters** or any other additional params you don't want to lose.

Answer (score 7):

```
redirect_to :controller => "controller_name", :action => "action_name", :id => x.id
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more explanation. Just a code example is really not enough.

Answer (score 7):

Route your path, and take the `params`, and return:

```
redirect_to controller: "client", action: "get_name", params: request.query_parameters and return
```

Answer (score 6):

**routes.rb**

```
 match 'controller_name/action_name' => 'controller_name#action_name', via: [:get, :post], :as => :abc
```

Any controller you want to redirect with parameters are given below:

```
redirect_to abc_path(@abc, id: @id), :notice => "message fine"
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Rails 6, you can simply call  `redirect_to` followed by the path you wish to redirect to such as `home_path`, and then pass is a hash of key-value pairs.

example:

```
redirect_to home_path(name: 'Jason', needs: 'help with rails', help: true)
```

After this, you will be able to retrieve these values from  the params hash.

ex

`params[:name]`

to retrieve the string 'Jason'