# how to pass a variable with redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller destroy function, I would like to redirect to index after the item deleted, and I would like to pass a variable called 'checked' when redirect:

```
def destroy
    @Car = Car.find(params[:id])
    checked = params[:checked]

    if @car.delete != nil

    end

    redirect_to cars_path #I would like to pass "checked" with cars_path URL (call index)
end
```

how to pass this 'checked' variable with **cars_path** so that in my index function I can get it?? (**cars_path** calls *index* function)

```
def index
 checked = params[checked]
end
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430247/passing-parameters-in-rails-redirect-to

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you do not mind the params to be shown in the url, you could:

```
redirect_to cars_path(:checked => params[:checked])
```

If you really mind, you could pass by session variable:

```
def destroy
  session[:tmp_checked] = params[:checked]
  redirect_to cars_path
end

def index
  checked = session[:tmp_checked]
  session[:tmp_checked] = nil # THIS IS IMPORTANT. Without this, you still get the last checked value when the user come to the index action directly.
end
```