# 'Redirect_ to' with parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to redirect to another method from the current method. Also I want to pass an instance variable with it. What is the syntax to do that?

currently I have:

```
redirect_to :action => 'contact'
```

Now how do I modify the above statement to also pass an instance variable?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Possible duplicat [how to pass a variable with redirect_to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887321/how-to-pass-a-variable-with-redirect-to)

Comment: do you mean from the current controller action to another action?

Comment: @dax, yes I want to call another action from the current controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass instance variables in URLs but what you can do instead is pass on the id or some other string, which you can use to obtain the data from the model(s).

For example, if you want to pass the data from `User.find(10)`, you can do:

```
redirect_to :action => 'contact', :user_id => 10
```

The next controller/action can then do `User.find(params[:user_id])` to retrieve that data.