# passing a variable from controller to view in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I want to pass a variable value from controller to view as shown below

> ## controller (.rb)

```
redirect_to root_url, :some_var => 'true or false'
```

> ## view (root_url.html.erb)

```
<% if :some_var %>
   #do something
<% else %>
   #do something else.
```

can anyone provide me an idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicated and answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887321/how-to-pass-a-variable-with-redirect-to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then just pass that variable as query string

```
redirect_to root_url(foo: 'bar')
```

This will produce url like

```
example.com?foo=bar
```

Another way is to use flash object

```
redirect_to root_url, notice: "This is some info to convey"
```

Flash to convey temp variable:

```
flash[:foo] = 'bar'
redirect_to root_url

# View
<% if flash[:foo] %>
  <%= "This is #{flash[:foo]} value" %>
```

Comment: But how to check the value of foo in view or template.

Comment: Can I use anything else than flash. Or may be just :foo

Comment: That's nice. `flash` has benefit that it got removed in next request. However, please still be aware of this pattern and not abuse session/flash :)

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do this is to render, not redirect, since you're not quite finishing the whole action. then just use instance variables in the controller action:

```
@some_var = true or false
render root_url
```

root:

```
if @some_var 
   do blah
```