# When a form fails "render 'edit'" uses the update action instead of the edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Say a user is editing their settings, it fails and the url is now /user instead of /user/edit and it is using the update action in the user controller instead of going back to the edit action. Is there any way to change this?

I have instance variables in the edit action and now I also have to put them in the update action so the page still works when the form fails. This is something that is easy to forget to do. Can you tell `render 'edit'` to not only render edit.html.erb but also use the edit action?

maybe something like `render 'edit', :action => 'edit'`?

Comment: You can do `redirect_to :action=>:edit` but you will then need to pass any variables you need e.g. the instance variable that has the errors. This question deals with passing variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887321/how-to-pass-a-variable-with-redirect-to

Answer (score 0):

You can define a private method that will set your instance variables. Then re-use this method in both actions.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use :`before_action` to load the variables for both `edit` and `update`.

```
before_action :load_edit_variables, only: [:edit, :update]
```