# Call javascript function on action success

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller called USER_LOCATIONS. What I want is that after the success of the action create the page redirects to another controller and that a specific javascript function loads in this moment

It is because I need run the function only when the user_location is created and then never more

How can I do this?

-----------EDIT------------
USER_LOCATIONS

```
def create
            @user_location = UserLocation.new(user_location_params)

            respond_to do |format|
              if @user_location.save
                @resource_is_new = 'OK'  
                format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Ramal selecionado com sucesso.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user_location }

              else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @user_location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              end
            end
        end
```

HOMECONTROLLER, INDEX VIEW

```
<% if @resource_is_new %>
  <%= content_for :extra_scripts do %>
    <script>
      alert('teste');
    </script>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Javascript does not run on the controller it runs on the view. can you post the code that you have

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extra_scripts` content block to call the Javascript function only when that particular view is loaded. If you only want to run this JS following a redirect when the resource has been created, then you can set an instance variable in the controller action to specify this:

```
<% if @resource_is_new %>
  <%= content_for :extra_scripts do %>
    <script>
      // call your function here
    </script>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Place this at the bottom of your redirect view, and make sure to set the `resource_is_new` instance var in the controller action when it has succeeded.

Comment: But how can i pass this instance var to another controller view with redirect_to?

Comment: You can pass it as a param, or store in the session. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887321/how-to-pass-a-variable-with-redirect-to

Comment: I Edited the question