# redirect_to with params. How to pass them to my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new with rails. I have used the `redirect_to` with `params` in my action, but now I don't know how to show these `params` to my view?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this variants:

- `redirect_to controller: 'thing', action: 'edit', id: 3, something: 'else'`
- `redirect_to thing_path(@thing, foo: params[:foo])`

Also, this [link should be helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430247/passing-parameters-in-rails-redirect-to).

Comment: If you want to get controller and action name from previous page, then use `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)`. It'll output `=> {:controller => "posts", :action => "show"}`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually if you have sent something with redirect - you have passed it like GET params. In this case you can access them from your `params` hash.

If you redirect like:

```
redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'edit', :id => 1, :param_a => 1, :param_b => 2
```

You have url like:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit?param_a=1&param_b=2
```

So you can access `:param_a` and `:param_b` in your view from params hash:

```
<%= params[:param_a] %>
<%= params[:param_b] %>
```

Comment: ok, now it works. But how to hide these informations from my url?

Comment: Actually you can't because they are GET params.

Comment: is there others way to pass my parameters to the view??

Comment: Please tell more, what you have to show in your view, so I can understand your problem deeply. It would be better if you can post here your view and your controller method where you are redirecting to. Also data in your which you are sending in your redirect URL is also important.

Comment: If i need to pass, critical info, i can't put this information on my url.

Comment: Yes you can't. If it is critical info, you have to find another approach (more secure). Even redirect with data passing with POST is not good solution. Technically you have store data and assign your data to some object in your system. Then you can access that data from your object.

Comment: If this information is critical, you can store it in a session like this: session[:my_critical_info] = [param1, param2]. session works like a hash.

Comment: As of today, RuboCop tells me to *"Use the new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax. [Style/HashSyntax]"* which I will tell you now. The new redirect would then be: `redirect_to controller: 'users', action: 'edit', id: 1, param_a: 1, param_b: 2`. Thank you for this great answer nevertheless.