# how to pass variables between handlers (routes) in sinatra (without flash, sessions, @@class_variable or $global_variable)?

Tags: variables, sinatra, action

Say you have:

```
get '/' do
  haml :index
end
```

get '/form' do
  haml :form
end

post '/form' do
  @message = params[:message]
  redirect to ('/') --- how to pass @message here?
end

I'd like the @message instance variable to be available (passed to) in "/" action as well, so I can show it in haml view.
How can I do that without using session, flash, a @@class_variable, or db persistence ?

I'd simply like to pass values as if I was working with passing values between methods.

I don't want to use session cookies because user could have them turned off, I don't like it being a class variable which is exposed to all code, and I don't need to overhead of a db.

Thanks

edit:

This is another question explaining a very easy way to deal with this in rails

[Passing parameters in rails redirect_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430247/passing-parameters-in-rails-redirect-to)

Following is more info on the topic i gathered from forums, which works in rails but, to my experience,  not in Sinatra (but please check it out because I might have done something wrong):

> If you are redirecting to action2 at the end of action1, just append
>   the value to the end of the redirect:

```
my_var = <some logic>
redirect_to :action => 'action2', :my_var => my_var
```

on the same thread another user proposes the folowing:

```
def action1
  redirect_to :action => 'action2', :value => params[:current_varaible]
end
def action2
 puts params[:value].inspect
end
```

source: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/134953

Can something like this work in Sinatra? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
before do
  @message = params[:message]
end
```

and `@message` should be available in any route

EDIT

```
post '/form' do
  @message = params[:message]
  #redirect to ('/') --- how to pass @message here?
  haml :index, locals: {msg: @message}
end
```

Don't use `redirect` then you may pass `locals` hash. In your index.haml  `msg` variable should be available.

Comment: Thanks for providing 2 different solutions... 
Anyway both of those are not exactly what I needed... In my code a redirect is necessary for code consistency and maintenability, so the closest solution could be your first one with a few tweaks to make it more "strict". However I am still saddened that there is not a standard and safe way to pass a variable from a route to another one, for example as you would do in rails. Basically I want to pass a var like when you pass it from a function to another, without altering the inherently defined scope.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of is to stuff things in `̀Thread.current[:variableName]`.     I make no claims that this is the best or safe solution.    In particular, that hash entry should be deleted / set to nil once you are done with it.