# Rails Search form - Pass parameter from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, view, controller, routes

I have the following in my view:

```
<%= form_for :search do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :search %>
      <%= f.text_field :search  %>
      <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

I am attempting to create a `post` action from the `f.submit` button which will route to a specific controller action. I then need that action to redirect back to my initial view, but pass in the `text_field` parameter on the redirect. How can I access the `text_field` parameter in my view as well as pass it through a redirect?

Comment: Why did you remove your edit?

Comment: My apologies - I was attempting to make the question more clear and deleted too much information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is from this question: [Passing parameters in rails redirect_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430247/passing-parameters-in-rails-redirect-to)

```
redirect_to search_path({ :search => params[:search] })
```

Comment: i wouldn't use `request.parameters` unless i really have to, `params` is the standard and preferred way to access HTTP params in rails controllers

Comment: good point, and i'd actually probably only pass what's necessary.  see updated answer

Comment: It's good to see both ways - There's a few times I will want to pass all parameters, others I would only need a specific param. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

your parameters will come in a normal hash, and you can access them via `params[:search][:search]` in your controller.

generally just look into the rails server log, you can see the data your browser sends to rails right there

Comment: I was gonna (and did temporarily) downvote this, but it appears to answer the current edited version of the question.  it appears he removed the part that mine actually answers which yours doesn't answer at all

Comment: @TMP sorry about that, i didn't realize that he edited the question, so it seemed like a wrong answer. canceled my down vote :)

Comment: thanks! still trying to figure out why he edited a second time, but at least one of use are helping! haha happy holidays