# How to add params to redirect_to and a route (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to add a param to a url path with:

```
redirect_to user_home_url(current_user, popup: true)
```

I want to generate:

```
http://user_home_url?popup=true
```

For some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Please note I'm NOT using the following format:

```
redirect_to :controller => 'controller_name', :action => action_name, :param =>'param'
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.0.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameters in rails redirect\_to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430247/passing-parameters-in-rails-redirect-to)

Comment: Not sure if it's the exact same issue, as it didn't answer my problem. What is what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please explain what is different between your problem and the possible duplicate. They seem the same based on the details you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `user_home_path` instead of `user_home_url`:

```
redirect_to user_home_path(current_user, popup: true)
```

Comment: undefined method `user_home_path' for #<CallsController:0x007fbb78674c70>.

Comment: How are your routes defined?

Comment: Can't I just use user_home_url and add params?

Comment: authenticated :user do
      root to: 'home#index'
    end

Comment: The `user_home_url` helper is made by you or by the Rails framework from the routes.rb? In the former case, then you should consider modifying the routes file in order to make Rails create the helpers for you (both *_path and *_url helpers)

Comment: Sorry to waste your time Claudix, just noticed it's helper I have :( I'll remove this post. sorry again

Comment: It's OK. No problem :-)