# Ruby/Rails: How do I convert a keys-values string(with array value included) to valid hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, parameters

I got an issue converting form params to string of **keys** and **values** and then convert it to hash to use this hash as redirect params later.

Everything works fine about one-value params, but I have 2 sets of checkbox there and I am not sure how to handle these checkboxes.

I use something like:

```
search_params.concat("categories=[#{params[:categories].map {|a| %Q('#{a}')}.join(', ')}]")
```

and to add checkboxes to string and then

```
Hash[last_search.sub('?', '').scan /([^=]+)=([^&]+)[&$]/]
```

Above statement to get all redirect params as hash.

As already said, this works perfect but skips all the '**key: array**' pairs, so I can not check for these params in my form after redirect.

Please help me understand how to handle it or how to do it in different and better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can avoid converting params to hash and back by passing hash to redirect_to

[Passing parameters in rails redirect_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430247/passing-parameters-in-rails-redirect-to)

Comment: You are right! Initially this task was a bit different, so I started it form the wrong side. After Your comment I understood that I overcomplicate this :)
So now I just serialize my params to save it in DB and from here all other stuff is done much easier. Thanks!