# redirect_to with additional parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a noob.

```
redirect_to users_url, notice: 'Succeed.'

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

Then I add a `message` and it failed:

```
redirect_to users_url, notice: 'Succeed.', message: 'test'

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1><%= params[:message] %></h1> # no result
<h1><%= message %></h1> # name error
```

What's the differences between `users_url` and `users_path`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters in rails redirect\_to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430247/passing-parameters-in-rails-redirect-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to pass it in the `_url` or `_path` method:

```
redirect_to users_url(message: 'test'), notice: 'Succeed.'
```

This will redirect to the absolute path for `/users`, setting the flash notice to "Succeed." with an additional parameter of `message` set to "test".

To answer your second question, `_path` returns a relative path to the route whereas `_url` returns an absolute URL to the route:

```
users_url # => http://www.example.com/users
users_path # => /users
```

`_url` is useful, for example, in emails or for links that will live outside your app.