# Rails - redirect_to not sending params as intended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have the following line of code:

```
redirect_to dynamic_page_path(page), corporate_contact_form: 'bla'
```

When I trigger this redirect and check my logs, it is being sent without the corporate_contact_form param, just the page.

I've checked the docs and believe I've entered all that's needed, however apparently not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That redirect would probably work to send parameters if you were redirecting to a post method and not a get.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems to me that you mixed the syntaxes, which could be:

```
redirect_to controller: 'dynamic_page', action: 'edit', corporate_contact_form: 'bla'
```

or

```
redirect_to dynamic_page_path(page, corporate_contact_form: 'bla')
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1430309/7219974) should be helpful for you.

Comment: I've tried 

    redirect_to dynamic_page_path(page, corporate_contact_form: 'bla')

And it's still not passing in the corporate_contact_form parameter, just the dynamic_page_id

Answer (score 0):

Place your parameters inside [the flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash):

```
redirect_to dynamic_page_path(page), flash: { corporate_contact_form: 'bla' }
```

Only a few keys can be used outside the flash: `:alert` and `:notice`. That is why you might find in the docs things like:

```
redirect_to dynamic_page_path(page), notice: 'Hello'
```

Not all parameters can be placed without a flash, though.

Comment: You can add custom flash types with `add_flash_types :info, :error, :warning` and so on, and use them like you did with `notice`

Comment: However this is not an answer to the question posted, it asks for `params` that are not working.

Comment: Yeah, I may have got wrong the question by looking at the position of the closing `)` and early assuming it would be related to flash. Didn't know about `add_flash_types`, though. Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a syntax problem. You need to include the params you want to send as part of the args for your path helper. It should be:

`redirect_to dynamic_page_path(page, corporate_contact_form: 'bla')`