# Every purchase receipt is populated with the same product info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have a store where you can buy digital products via download. Every product purchased (I've tested multiple products) displays the same product's information (title, art_link, and download_url) on the thank you page right after purchase.

What Am I doing wrong here that is preventing it from loading the correct data from the pack just purchased?

I'm using Stripe for payments. Everything else works perfectly, the money goes through, the email is sent and links to the receipt, the UUID works, etc.

**UPDATE:** I've checked my DB and Everything is saving correctly. The only problem is with the `purchases/show` view not rendering properly.

**purchases/show:**

```
<p><b><%= @pack.title %></b></p>
<%= image_tag("#{@pack.art_link}", :alt => "#{@pack.title} sound library.", :width => 330, :height => 330, class: "img-center img-responsive shade") %>
<p><a class="btn btn-success top-drop" href="<%= @pack.download_url %>" target="_blank">Download Files</a></p>
```

**purchases_controller:**

```
def show
  @purchase = Purchase.find_by_uuid(params[:id])
  @pack = Pack.find(@purchase.product_id)
  set_meta_tags noindex: true
end
```

**Purchase model:**

```
attr_accessor :download_token
after_create :email_purchaser

def to_param
  uuid
end

def email_purchaser
  PurchaseMailer.purchase_receipt(self).deliver
end

def Purchase.new_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def create_download
  self.download_token = Purchase.email.new_token
  update_attribute(:download, Purchase.email(download_token))
  update_attribute(:download_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
end
```

**charges_controller:**

```
def create
  pack = Pack.find(params[:product_id])

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken],
  )

  # Amount in cents
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => pack.price_in_cents,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd',
  )

  purchase = Purchase.create(
    email: params[:stripeEmail],
    card: params[:stripeToken],
    amount: pack.price_in_cents,
    description: charge.description,
    currency: charge.currency,
    customer_id: customer.id,
    product_id: pack.id,
    uuid: SecureRandom.uuid,
  )

  redirect_to purchase

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end
```

Thank you very much, this really has me stuck.

**Routes.rb:**

```
resources :packs, :path => 'products'
resources :charges
resources :purchases, only: [:show]
```

Comment: Have you checked if you are loading different purchase every single time (different `params[:id]` in the `PurchasesController`)? Also, can you add `routes.rb` to your post (only the part related to purchases)?

Comment: @MrShemek Hey, thanks. I'm seeing a different URL (UUID) for 3 different purchases I tested so I think it would be a different id. I'm not quite sure though, did you mean something else and how would I check it? I've updated my question with the routes.

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with Rails, but when you `redirect_to purchase`, it looks like the `purchases_controller` is then using the ID parameter to find the product. But I don't see how that ID is getting passed, do you need to [explicitly set it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430247/passing-parameters-in-rails-redirect-to)?  i.e use `purchase.product_id` when you redirect from `charges_controller`

Comment: @karllekko If you take a look at the `charges_controller`, the purchase data is actually being populated by a charge going through (a successful payment). `purchase = Purchase.create` Each pack is purchased on its own `show` view so the line `product_id: pack.id` means it will take the `pack.id` from the `pack` just bought and use that as the value for `product_id`.

Comment: @karllekko it is not needed ([source](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to)).
@Jake - I have checked similar solution and everything works fine in my case. I think that the only option to check that is to put `binding.pry` in controllers and views and check what object is loaded as `@pack`.

Comment: @MrShemek So does it matter where I put this line, or would I need to put it right after the code I'm trying to find? **P.S. I am using `friendly_id` if that would make a difference.**

Comment: @Jake let's move to the chat; it will be quicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved on a chat.

In `routes.rb`, there were following lines:

```
get 'purchase' => 'purchases#show', as: 'purchase' 
...
resources :purchases, only: [:show]
```

So when OP called: `redirect_to purchase` the URL was:

```
http://localhost:3000/purchase.4c77a556-299e-4611-b683-3ff6eb672738
```

From that, the `params[:id]` was `nil`. In DB, there were 4 purchases with UUID equal `nil`, and the first one was always returned (because `find_by` returns the first matched record).